# Duplicate rendering ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this simple create.js.erb file that submits the form through ajax:

Create.js.erb:

```
$(".answers").append("<%= j render(@answer) %>");
$(".val").val("");
$(".count").text("Answers (<%= Answer.count %>)");
```

It works and all but it creates a temporarily duplicate as well (it goes away when I refresh the page).

On my other form it worked as expected. same code but different class selectors. The only difference is that I have an extra div on this one.

Show.html.haml (The file where the duplicate occurs)

```
    .row.down
        .col-md-9.counter_text
            - if @question.answers.count < 1
                %h4.text-muted No answers yet. Be the first to answer!
        .col-md-9.padDown.answers
            = render :partial => @question.answers
            .hr
```

Answer's partial:

```
= div_for(answer) do
    .media
        - if @question.user.avatar.blank?
            %a{:href => "#", :onclick => "return false;", :class=>"pull-left"}
                %img{:src => "/assets/user.png", :width => "40"}
        - else
            = link_to "/users/"+"#{@question.user.id}", :class => "pull-left" do
                = image_tag answer.avatar, :width => "40"
        .clearfix.visible-sm

        .media-body
            .small
                - if answer.answer_id == current_user.id 
                    %p.pull-right
                        = link_to 'delete', [@question, answer], :method => :delete, :remote => true, :class => "black"
                %h5.media-heading
                    = answer.username
                %small.text-muted.media-heading
                    = time_ago_in_words(answer.created_at)
            %p.hidden-xs.down.black
                = h(answer.body)
            %p.black.down
                = link_to h(answer.demo), "http://"+h(answer.demo)
            .hr
```

My other form (the one that works):

```
    .row.down
        .col-md-9.test
            = render :partial => @campaign.comments
            .hr
```

Any reason on why it's happening?

**edit**

Here's an image to exemplify what's happening more:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I was getting a duplicate answer, is because of the parent div. I mistakenly gave the parent a class called `answers` as well. Renaming it fixed the problem.